# JQuery onclick div hide/show/reset for the next time clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Simple question from a newbie:

> How do I reset/restart a function after completing the time of (500
>   ms) in order to repeat the function each time I click on a specific
>   button?

**FIRST PART OF THE CODE WORKS**

- my div is disappearing after 500ms fading out

```
$('.animate-this').click(function () {
    $('p').show().delay(500).fadeOut();
});
```

**SECOND PART IS MISSING**

- I would need to reset the fuction in order to repeated immediately...
  I guess there is a very simple solution for that..

Comment: what do you mean by "reset the function in order to repeat it"? you want `<p>` to keep showing up and fade out?

Comment: @CapitanFindus exactly, I want my div showing up and disappearing on click but also "after completing the animation" to be able to repeated again if I would click "again" on my button

Comment: any idea @CapitanFindus?

Answer (score 0):

fadeOut accepts a callback function. You can use that

```js
function animate() {
  $('p').show().delay(500).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    animate()
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @brk.  Could you show me there how to fix [this](https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg)?  after push the button ```.animate-this``` it work only ones..

Comment: have a look here in case you would be so kind to help me (https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg) thanks in advance!

Comment: this for me still not worked  unfortunately ```function animate() {
  $('p').show().delay(500).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    animate()
  });
}```